# Adding Matarial date picker value to textview

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, datepicker

I wrote a custom datepicker for android for adding date of birth. Code is as given below:
**`layout.xml`**:

```
<!--Date of Birth Label -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
            <EditText android:id="@+id/dob"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Date of Birth"
                android:onClick="showDatePicker"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

**`MainActivity.java:`**

```
package com.emc.kulkaa.dellcsrmate;

import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class RegistrationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link_login);
        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(RegistrationActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    public void showDatePicker(View v) {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new MyDatePickerFragment();
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "Date Picker");
    }

}
```

Here is date fragment:

```
package com.emc.kulkaa.dellcsrmate;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Calendar;

/**
 * Created by kulkaa on 1/18/2018.
 */

public class MyDatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), dateSetListener, year, month, day);
    }

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateSetListener =
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "selected date is " + view.getYear() +
                            " / " + (view.getMonth() + 1) +
                            " / " + view.getDayOfMonth(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            };
}
```

Above code works successfully. Value selected in custom datepicker appears in `Toast` successfully.

Now I want selected value to appear in `EditText` instead of appearing in toast. How can I do it by modifying fragment code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simple write this code onDate selected

```
((TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.link_login)).setText("date");
```

so your code looks

```
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "selected date is " + view.getYear() +
                            " / " + (view.getMonth() + 1) +
                            " / " + view.getDayOfMonth(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    String date ="selected date is " + view.getYear() +
                            " / " + (view.getMonth() + 1) +
                            " / " + view.getDayOfMonth();

                    ((TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.link_login)).setText(date);
                }
```